# Was kernel 4.4.0-65 update pulled back?

Tags: kernel

24 hours ago, Linux kernel 4.4.0-65 appeared as an update on Ubuntu 16.04 update servers.  I did not do the update at that time because I was too busy to restart the system because of the update.  I attempted to do the update 12 hours ago though and although all other updates appeared and installed properly, the kernel update had vanished.

Kernel 4.4.0-65 update is still nowhere to be found at this time.  I have changed update servers just to ensure that this was not a local server issue but the results were the same.

Does anyone know what has happened?

Thank you!

Comment: Get it here from this [link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-headers-4.4.0-65)

Comment: @George The question is not how to install 4.4.0-65 but why it was available yesterday (not through *xenial-proposed*) and is no longer there today (except in *xenial-proposed*).

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes I know wasn't trying to answer that just showing where the OP could get it...

Comment: It was definitely in updates for a short time. One of my xenial machines got the update, the other one did not.

Answer (score 3):

After some search I found out that it was pulled back actually because of critical errors like this one here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1669611

Thank you all though!  :)